# How do I determine human-readable file size in Julia?

Tags: julia

I would like to display to the user a human-readable file size in Julia.

Python, for instance, has `humanize.naturalsize()`:

```
>>> humanize.naturalsize(1000000)
'1.0 MB'
>>> humanize.naturalsize(1000000, binary=True)
'976.6 KiB'
```

How can I achieve this in Julia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a package to do this, but the [Python code](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize/blob/master/humanize/filesize.py) is very short and should translate nicely to Julia.

EDIT: In fact, I decided to make a package out of it: [Humanize.jl](https://github.com/IainNZ/Humanize.jl), which you can install with `Pkg.add("Humanize")`

Comment: Let me know if you need any more arguments/control over the output.